# How to join with nested array in MongoDB driver for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I am using MongoDB shell version v3.6.3.
I have two collections 1. User 2. Business
I have given sample data below.

```
user
********
_id : 1
username : "joyjeba2"
mobile_number : 9840347197,
profile_url :"http://localhost:3001/user/1599214209351_dp1.jpg"
saved_products :[1,2]

Business
*****
_id:1
name : "businessname1"
location :"location",
contact_number:123456,
Products : [
{   "name": "product",
    "tags": [
        "shoes",
        "slippers"
    ],
    "description": "its a simple description",
    "lower_price": 20,
    "higher_price": 30,
    "min_order": 20,
    "units": "count",
    "media_urls": [
        "http://localhost:3001/product/1586703106075_DP1.jpg"
    ],
    "_id": 1
}
{   "name": "product",
    "tags": [
        "shoes",
        "slippers"
    ],
    "description": "its a simple description",
    "lower_price": 20,
    "higher_price": 30,
    "min_order": 20,
    "units": "count",
    "media_urls": [
        "http://localhost:3001/product/1586703106075_DP1.jpg"
    ],
    "_id": 2
},  
]
```

now i want to make a join from `saved_products` in user collection to products in  business collection.

Expected result is:

```
_id : 1
username : "joyjeba2"
mobile_number : 9840347197,
profile_url :"http://localhost:3001/user/1599214209351_dp1.jpg"
saved_product : [
{   "name": "product",
    "tags": [
        "shoes",
        "slippers"
    ],
    "description": "its a simple description",
    "lower_price": 20,
    "higher_price": 30,
    "min_order": 20,
    "units": "count",
    "media_urls": [
        "http://localhost:3001/product/1586703106075_DP1.jpg"
    ],
    "_id": 1
    "_business_id":1,   
    "business_name" : "businessname1"
    "location" :"location"
}
{   "name": "product",
    "tags": [
        "shoes",
        "slippers"
    ],
    "description": "its a simple description",
    "lower_price": 20,
    "higher_price": 30,
    "min_order": 20,
    "units": "count",
    "media_urls": [
        "http://localhost:3001/product/1586703106075_DP1.jpg"
    ],
    "_id": 2,
    "_business_id":1,   
    "business_name" : "businessname1"
    "location" :"location"
},  
],
```

I am able to do this when product is separate collection (with the help of lookup and unwind). But here product is inside a business collection as a nested document.  How can i achieve this. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$lookup` using pipeline, pass `saved_products` in let
- `$unwind` deconstruct `Products` array
- `$match` product id
- `$mergeObjects` to merge business fields and product fields
- `$replaceRoot` to replace merged object in root

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "business",
      let: { saved_products: "$saved_products" },
      pipeline: [
        { $unwind: "$Products" },
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$Products._id", "$$saved_products"] } } },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
              $mergeObjects: [
                "$Products",
                {
                  _business_id: "$_id",
                  business_name: "$name",
                  location: "$location"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "saved_products"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ESiiTL1CoVB)

Comment: Thanks. It works @turivishal. I Need to change *replaceWith* with *replaceRoot* since my version is 3.6.3.